# Closed convex subset without unique minimal distance point

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am searching for an example of a Banach space $X$ and a closed, convex subset $A\subset X$ so that there is a $x\in X$ for which we cannot find a unique $a\in A$ with $\text{dist}(x,A) = ||x-a||$.

In my opinion that is not possible, but an exercise of my lecture asks me to find such an example. Can someone help me?

Comment: A hint: Perhaps it would be beneficial to think of any norms you may have encountered which have convex subsets (that are not merely singletons) of their unit spheres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $\mathbb R^2$ with $\|(x,y)\|=|x|+|y|,\ A=\{(1-t)(1,0)+t(0,1): 0\le t\le 1\}$ and $\vec x=(0,0).$

Comment: That works well, thank you!